# Use PHP / GD to Save Binary Data as a JPEG Without Losing Metadata

Tags: php, gd, jpeg, binary-data

I have an image that is being fed to my PHP script as binary data. I want to save this image as a jpeg to a directory on my server. I can accomplish this with the following code:

```
// create image resource from the binary data
$image = imagecreatefromstring($binary_data);

// save the image resource as a jpeg
imagejpeg($image, $directory);
```

The problem is that when I do this, I think it is creating a new image that contains new metadata. Is there a way I can save the binary data as an image and preserve the original binary data?

Comment: files are just strings why not just write the string directly

Comment: When you say meta info, do you mean the created timestamp etc, or the EXIF data?

Comment: All of it - timestamps and EXIF data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just save `$binary_data` instead of passing it through GD
`file_put_contents($directory, $binary_data)`

Answer (score 0):

With Meta data, you can read the data via [iptcparse()](http://php.net/iptcparse) and embed it back in via [iptcembed()](http://php.net/iptcembed)

This comment will pretty much do exactly what you want -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php#85887

For EXIF data, you can read it via [exif-read-data()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) but there isn't a way of writing that data back to the file, but hopefully that should be enough to get you started in the right direction.